# Create mediaplayer alternate for live stream android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In reference to my question at:

[Android Lollipop prepareAsync() takes a long time to return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208956/android-lollipop-prepareasync-takes-a-long-time-to-return)

I would like to go to a lower level. Does anyone know of a way to set up and play a live stream WITHOUT using a MediaPlayer object? Nothing fancy, just connect and play. No retrieval of song info or anything else.

Please see my other question (still unanswered) for details.